# Get Identity after selecting from distinct result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

### i have 2 tables ( Model_Table , Items_Table)

```
Model_Tabl ( ID, ModelName, ModelQuantity)
Items_Tabl ( I_Code, IName, ID)
```

after inserting new row into (Model_Table) - Triggers insert multi row into (Items_Table) Depend on ModelQuantity from (Model_Table)
, and until now its work fine

I Created `"select distinct ModelName , Sum(ModelQuantity) group by ModelName"`
and i got result fine

**My question is** :

When i select model name from (DISTINCT) query i want to know which (ID) I selected from (Model_Table)

Model_ID (TO) Model_Name = 1 (TO) Many
ty

Comment: Is the id field in your model_tabl table an identity field?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need the `DISTINCT` there, so you can get rid of it. And then, you can try this:

```
SELECT ID, ModelName, SUM(ModelQuantity) Quantity
FROM Model_Tabl 
GROUP BY ID, ModelName
```

Ok, as I explained on my comment, if you have multiple IDs with the same name, you need to choose one, either the max or the min ID (it still doesn't make sense that you are going to end up just choosing one ID when you actually need to identify that ID), but well, here it is:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) ID, ModelName, SUM(ModelQuantity) Quantity
FROM Model_Tabl 
GROUP BY ModelName
```

Comment: i dont need to douplecate model name in result

Comment: @KaremKhalil So, you don't want duplicate model names (meaning that you **are** getting duplicates now), but you want to identify the ID from where the model name came from?, don't you see the contradiction in that?. Currently, you have multiple ID's with the same model name, so if you don't want duplicates, you need to **choose** one of those IDs, it can be the minimum or the maximum (but it won't make it a right result anyway). Updated my answer with that kinda query.

Comment: you are right iam working on it it now and i will tell you what i got soon ( iam thinking to creat another table to hold items for inserting and another one to hold query results )
ty

Answer (score 0):

just do:

```
select ID, ModelName , Sum(ModelQuantity) group by ID, ModelName
```

as long as ID and ModelName are 1-to-1, you're good.

(Btw, your "distinct" here is superfluous - `Select distinct a,b,c from tbl` is simply shorthand for `Select a,b,c from tbl group by a,b,c`)

Comment: ty very much your answer helpped me  - but i dont want to douplecate Model Name ( i need to edit my question ) ty again

Comment: Model ID |TO| Model Name = 1 |TO| Many

Answer (score 0):

You have an identity column in the model_table, but you don't appear to be using it in the query where you check the ModelQuantity field.  Don't you want to do something like this?

```
select ModelQuantity
from Model_table
where id = @@identity
```

?

Comment: yes i nees quantity i will use identity colmun for difine which model i need to incres it ( iam thinking to creat another 2 tabl ) ty for help